# LongListMultiSelector, items are clipped

Tags: windows-phone-8, clipping, longlistselector

In Windows Phone 8 have a LongListMultiSelector with a ItemTemplate that is a grid with 2 columns.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Each item has a **TextBlock** in the **First Column** and a **Button** in the **Second Column**

The problem is that when I run the application, the button in the second column gets cut. It appears clipped, so its rightmost border doesn't appear.

[image: Snapshot]

What's the problem here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution would be overriding LongListMultiSelector's **ItemContainerStyle** and setting right padding and margins, but surprisingly this doesn't help. The workaround I came up with is to set right side margins on your elements inside each item (on Buttons in your case). Have you tried this?